# How to use default notification style?

Tags: android, notifications, styles

I have the exact same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors).  I want my custom notifications text style to match the default notifications (Im just going to add a few extra views).  Unfortunately I don't fully understand the accepted answer.  I think I am meant to add to the XML code but not sure exactly what...
[image]

The accepted answer says" 
The solution is to use built-in styles. The style you need is TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent. Just apply this style and it will set the default text color for notifications (don't forget android: prefix, of course).
"

I cant get this to work!  In my custom notification below the line "android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" works (as it enlargens the text) but does not give the desired effect.

Here is my custom XML code...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/notContentTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/notImage" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/notContentText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below ="@id/notContentTitle"
 />
```

[Custom notification layouts and text colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally figured out what I was doing wrong... (basically I was using features from API 9 when I am only developing on API 8).

**Firstly, to use a default (platform) style use...**

style = "@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"

For example...

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="3dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/notContentTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/notImage" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    style = "@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/notContentText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below ="@id/notImage"
    style = "@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"    />
```

**Secondly to use the StatusBar default style use..**

style = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" or

style = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title",

etc, etc.

For example,

```
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/notContentText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below ="@id/notImage"
    style = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"   />
```

In my case this caused an error because I am still developing with Android 2.2 (API 8) whilst these StatusBar styles are for API 9 onwards.  (I know I should update :))

Useful links are;

[Android.com Applying Styles and Themes, Using Platform Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles)

[Android.com R.style reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

[StackOverflow.com Custom notification layouts and text colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)

[Android.com Android API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

Comment: Just so we're clear...there is no way to use default notification styles prior to API9, correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. As I have explained in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors/4935191#4935191), in API Level 8 and earlier there's only a hard-coded value, which can't be accessed.

Comment: The answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7320604/435605) does provide a way to find the color for 2.2-