# Get notification texts colors and background

Tags: android, eclipse, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I created notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();


NotificationManager notificationManager = 
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Because its android default notification that may look different on some devices, I would like to know the Title text color, content text color and background color (usually black or white), how can I do this?

Comment: What if you set `Color` by `n.setColor(ARGB);` ?

Comment: I'm asking because there is a method called `setColor` if you extend Notification.Builder which Returns the `Color`. Maybe that's interesting for you? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you'll find solution in these posts?

- [Custom notification layouts and text colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)
- [How to match text color with notification color bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983153/how-to-match-text-color-with-notification-color-bar)

Answer (score 2):

According to [QArea answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641270/get-notification-texts-colors-and-background/27646780#27646780) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983864/6126110) I have finally defined my `TextView` on custom notification layout like this for title:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Notification Title"/>
```

and for default text:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Notification description"/>
```

so basically only thing you need to do is add

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
```

or

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info"
```

to your `TextView`

PD: Sorry my english!