# custom status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to implement a custom status bar like the super status bar application from market [Super Statusbar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.firezenk.ssb&hl=en)

Till now I have no solution. Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: check this may be it will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) class. Essentially you place a View on top of the status bar (position 0, 0). You'll need to get the height right, use BroadcastReceivers and other APIs to update Views with the current device state (i.e. battery, signal, time, etc). This can be done, it is just very difficult.

Source: I am the developer of [StatusBar+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tombarrasso.android.wp7bar), the app which Super Status Bar is based on. It used to be open source in its alpha builds but is no longer available.