# How to change color of notification number count

Tags: android, colors, notifications

I am developing an app in which i am using notification manager to show missed calls to the user.

And i succeeded in showing the notifications but i want to change the color of notification number count.Currently it is green and i want to change it to **blue** or **red**.

how can i achieve this?
is it possible?

Please refer the snap from my application.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: IS that green color by default or that is set by you? I think you can use the styles for notification which android uses and modify that for your purpose.

Comment: green color is by default

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors/7320604#7320604

Comment: @ Archie.bpgc:nice sample,but it does not refere to color of number count.