# Android - Notification Remote View change text color so its visible

Tags: android, notifications

I'm writing an app the need to push a 3 line notification in older versions of Android so I'm using a remote view. The problem I'm having is that the text in the remote view is black, which is OK for Gingerbread, but in ICS and JellyBean the notification bar is black so the text isn't visible. 
Any ideas how I can have the text visible no matter what the system notification background color is? Should I just have an image as my own background?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom notification layouts and text colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title` for notif title and `@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"` for notif text instead of using your own color. These styles require API level 9.