# Android, Custom Notification, Giving me always white Text

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I am trying to make a custom notification bar, it works and all but when i test it in lollipop it's displaying the title and content text with white color text, it is good for kitkat because the notification bar is dark but not for lollipop.

How can i make it change to default color or at least detect the theme of the action bar so i can make an if statement to change the color of the text.

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:hint="Title Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:hint="Content Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="        "
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right2"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentRa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="12:12"
                android:text="12:12"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagenotiright"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
                android:layout_below="@+id/time"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE:

```
public void CustomNotification(String strtext) {
        // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.customnotification);

        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle);
        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
        // Send data to NotificationView Class
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
        intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
        intent.putExtra("String T", "");
        //intent.putExtra("Integer C", 0);

        // Open NotificationView.java Activity
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
                        // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                        // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        // Set RemoteViews into Notification
                .setContent(remoteViews);

        // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.mipmap.ic_action_chat);

        // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle));
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, strtext);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom notification layouts and text colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure, but you can try something like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
    // I am not sure of this method
    remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.text, Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: that is for detecting if the os is lollipop or lower versions

Comment: it worked, thank you so much, one more thing, so it is lollipop after SDK_INT > 20?

Comment: you want to change the color of the text, then change it in the if condition block.. change it to Color.BLUE or any other color