# Cannot change NotificationCompat MediaStyle text color

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building a media player app based on [Google's Universal Media Player](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer). Now I'm facing a problem with notification the player creates.

Codes to create notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mService);

notificationBuilder
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(
                        new int[]{playPauseButtonPosition})  // show only play/pause in compact view
                .setMediaSession(mSessionToken))
            .setColor(mNotificationColor)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setUsesChronometer(true)
            .setContentIntent(createContentIntent(description))
            .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
            .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
            .setLargeIcon(art);
```

This code makes the following notification:
[image]

After that I remove **.setColor(mNotificationColor)** portion from the code. I thought it makes the background of the notification white. But now the background turns to grey like this:
[image]

So now I want to set background color to white, this is easy part. `setColor` can do the job, but at that time I want the text color black. Cannot figure out how to change the text color. The icons of play/pause is also not changed even I supply black icons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try some custom notification like this:

When you use Notification and set the text by using built-in means, the following line creates the layout:

```
  RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            com.android.internal.R.layout.status_bar_latest_event_content);
```

The mentioned layout contains the following View which is responsible for viewing notification text:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
```

So the conclusion is that the needed style is TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent, which definition looks like this:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

And here are some ref.
Hope this will resolve your issue.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904407/android-custom-notification-giving-me-always-white-text)

Comment: I add `<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media" tools:override="true">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_primary_text</item>
    </style>` as this is the style name I found in the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/layout/notification_template_lines_media.xml). But nothing happens. Text color is still white.

Comment: the reason for using tools:override="true" is : _overriding @style/TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Title_Media which is marked as private in com.android.support:appcompat-v7. If deliberate, use tools:override="true", otherwise pick a different name.

Private resources should not be referenced; the may not be present everywhere, and even where they are they may disappear without notice.

To fix this, copy the resource into your own project instead._ this appears when I use without override.

Comment: what is your min sdk and which device youhave tested.

Comment: Try something like this :                        
         contentView.setTextColor(R.id.text2, statColor);

Comment: Min SDK version is 17 and I test on Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1

Comment: how can I set contentView.setTextColor? As the notification style is built in, set by `new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()`

Comment: Actually U need to change this inbild style and add their own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141363/discussion-between-neo-and-ratul).