# How to set Custom Font to Notification ContentTitle?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-typeface

I want to add a custom font to Notification Content Title(typeface).I am trying a different ways. Can you guys help me to set the font like news hunt notifications?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors post.

Comment: Have you tried setting a custom layout on your Notification with RemoteView?