# Change ImageButton depend on notification background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, android-view, android-resources

I have notification with custom RemoteView. I [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935191/3005202) change text color, depend on notification background color. But my black button still invisible on api<21, when background black too.
Is there any way to fix this without changing background?

Comment: how u set bg color

Comment: @SwapnilNandapure i meen default notification background color. It black on android < 5.0 and white on android >= 5.0. Furthermore some os can override this color

Comment: Okay u mean that u want to change background color of popup notification is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below code to set background color to your Remote View Notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not_icon)
  .setContentTitle(getCurrentSong().getTitle())
  .setContentIntent(notOpenOnClick);
// This is what sets the background color on <N devices
// It is an accent color on N+ devices
nBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
// Add actions via nBuilder.addAction()
// Set the style, setShowActionsInCompactView(0) means the first
// action you've added will be shown the non-expanded view
nBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
  .setShowActionsInCompactView(0));
```

Comment: thank you, but i not want change background, i want change icon

Comment: Ohh see previous lollipop u can use any image but from lollipop and above u want to use vector icon like transparent background and ur icon in white color. Like : https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/new_packs/126466-multimedia-collection.png  get one of them and use it.

Answer (score 0):

After research, i use black icons for api>=21, and white icons with black stroke for api < 21.