# how to change native notification Title Text color?

Tags: android, notifications

[image]

Hi, i'm trying to change native notification title color like in the picture, i searched for a week and found nothing ,can anyone please tell how to do it without implementing custom views? 
and if it not possible how i implement custom view that mimic native view and mimic native actions (like expand in bigview etc.) ?

Comment: You have to implement the custom views/ Remote view to achieve what you have mentioned. Have u seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After week of search and a lot of tears , i found this article =>for me ,with little tweaks , it was the best solution,
so for anyone searching custom notifications that mimic native one's 
you should try this article
[Custom Notifications that mimic native notifications behavior for Android](http://code.hootsuite.com/custom-notifications-for-android/)